# Force www in ELB

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I have ElasticBeanstalk application using ELB I am trying to enforce www before url. It works in case of standalone server but with ELB it fails. Is there anyway to enforce this with ELB.

Currently my .htaccess looks like this.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}:s on:(s)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Did you clear the cache?

Comment: You mean browser cache? That one I did.